# How to enable Ctrl-Option combinations with OS X

Tags: key-bindings, osx

I can't get simultaneous presses of Ctrl + Option and other keys to register in Emacs. For example, if I press Ctrl-h c (`describe-key-briefly`) and then Ctrl-Opt-f, it doesn't recognize that I've pressed any keys.

Ctrl key combinations (like C-f) work, Meta key combinations (like M-f) work, and Escape + Ctrl sequences work ( C-F translates to C-M-f). The behavior is the same if Emacs is run

I'm using Emacs 26.1, installed via Homebrew.

Comment: Are you using Emacs in a terminal?

Comment: I had the same behavior with Emacs in a terminal or in its own window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering for others who may have this problem. Another application (in my case Magnet, a window manager) was stealing specific combinations of Ctrl and Option.

Comment: Good. Please [come back in a couple days and accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/), since otherwise it will return to the home page at intervals.